# Isn't causality a disproof for the Copenhagen interpretation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, quantum-interpretations

In QM, each measurement result cannot be predicted, in other words, that is random. This being random has a great implication: if there is no rule to specify the results, so there is cause. This lack of cause is not something acceptable logically. In other words, the non-deterministic (that is stochastic) NATURE of, let's say, electrons, means that there is not enough causes to determine the results of the observations (so electron decides where to go for itself). So, how can one resolve this contradiction between the orthodox viewpoimt of QM and the causality conjecture?

Comment: Causality is not incompatible with probabilistic phenomena and so there is no contradiction.

Comment: This question amounts to: 'is causality the same thing as determinism?'. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108957/109928

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A meaningful distinction between determinism and causality](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108957/)

Comment: No it doesn't. I try to edit my question to be clearer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you mean determinism rather than causality?

Comment: No I meant the causality conjecture. I know the difference of causality and determinism but non of them can be held for stochastic processes that are truly random and they are both held for "random" events that are random due to lack of knowledge. So the difference doesn't show up in the case of stochasticity.

Comment: In fact the outcome of a measurement CAN be determined and in fact is certain if the system is prepared in an eigenstate of the measurement operator.

Comment: Is this possible for at least one measurement not be determinable? If yes, it would be a counterexample to the causality conjecture, as it implies that there is no rule (if there was any, we could potentially predict the outcome).

Comment: What is the 'causality conjecture'? Google gives no entry.

Comment: I think yoi know what causality is, and conjecture in Mathematics means a theorem not proven yet but no counterexample has been ever observed. Conjectures are specially common in number theory.

Comment: For an event to be causal, it is not a requirement that there be a unique effect to each cause. A given cause might have more than one possible effect with some being mutually exclusive. Which of the effects occur will be subject to a probability distribution. The Copenhagen interpretation merely posits that the specific effect pertaining to this cause is chosen at random according to the probability distribution, but it is still a result of the underlying cause. Any cause with a unique effect is said to have acted on a system in an eigenstate of the cause (some corollaries apply)

Comment: So you mean that a cause can cause several outcomes...I agree but only one of them happens: THE outcome that we observe due to the act of measurement. Now, the question is: which possible outcome happens? Note that different outcomes are happening due to a similar reasons, so, it seems that the cause is not enough to determine the outcome and so the outcome chooses itself what to be!

Comment: This means that the outcome is causing itself to change, which is impossible. So, in the case of assuming causality, we have arrived at this accepting causality is wrong OR an impossible thing. So, by assuming causality, we can arrive at this contradiction. That's what I meant.

Comment: No, there's no contradiction. Recognizing that the cause alone is not enough to determine the effect, in the case of a cause with multiple effects, does not logically lead to saying that causality must be wrong. This means that determinism is wrong. The future cannot be predicted, that is. Causality is still fine because, you'll notice, every effect that is observed has a corresponding cause that preceded it. There are no effects that occur before their cause nor that have no cause at all. So determinism is dead (we know this and are fine with it) but causality is fine

Comment: Additionally, the specific effect that occurs from the possible effects is random. A cause with multiple possible effects only has multiple "possible" effects prior to the cause occurring. We say "if cause x happens, effects y, z, and q are possible results". This means if cause x happens a lot of times, we expect to see some instances of each effect happen. For one trial, when x happens, it randomly forces the state to align with one effect. But because it was a possible effect, there's nothing required to choose that effect in order for causality to be preserved. Nothing forbids randomness.

Comment: Thank you Jim. I exactly know what you are talking about, but I am still confused. If you answer the following question, it would probably be resolved: if cause X has Y and Z effects, and Y and Z are mutually exclusive (i.e. can't happen at the same time), then at a given time, only one (let's say Y) is the effect and NOT Z. Why wasn't the other way around? Why the outcome wasn't Z at that moment but not Y? Does this have a cause? If yes, it cannot be X as we have already assumed that cause X has two effects Y and Z and has no preference. So, if X is not the cause, what is THAT cause?

Comment: Note that we're assuming the Copenhagen interpretation, so there's no hidden variable (or that OTHER cause). So, the answer is: there is no cause! So, causality is not held. Please let me know of any flaw in my argument in these two comments. If you tell if this argument is right, or if it is not, why is it false, then I would really appreciate that.

Comment: The answer is that right before measurement, the state exists as both at once. It is not that measurement caused one to happen and not the other. Both happen, but once a measurement is taken you only see one. I get that you're trying to say that there must be a cause for choosing one over the other, but no, there musn't. The probabilistic nature of quantum physics allows for causality to be held in this case. The probability density causes each result to be chosen a number of times along a large number of samples, but it would and should look completely random for just one trial.

Answer (score 0):

You, the OP, are right.  According to the Copenhagen interpretation the future is not predictable, because measurement is inherently probabilistic.

Here are some references that mention the problem of non-determinism (acausality) inherent in the Copenhagen interpretation: [Stanford.edu](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-copenhagen/), [utm.edu](https://www.iep.utm.edu/int-qm/), and [Oregon.edu](http://abyss.uoregon.edu/~js/21st_century_science/lectures/lec15.html).

The Many-Worlds interpretation is a frequently cited resolution of the apparent contradiction between QM and causality: it asserts that all possible futures coexist in the wave function.  The wave function itself is deterministic, although individual particle trajectories are not deterministic.

In the Many Worlds interpretation the future wave function is still unknowable (due to the uncertainty principle which makes exact measurement of a wave function impossible), so the future of the wave function is not predictable even though it is deterministic.

Comment: OP is not correct - there is no conflict between any interpretation of quantum mechanics and causality. We may not be able to precisely predict the state of a system in the future, but all possible predictions *do* satisfy causality.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "causality".  In https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/causality, a definition of causality is "The principle that everything has a cause".  In that sense, wave function collapse is *not* deterministic, because there is nothing that can possibly predict the outcome of a QM experiment except in a probabilistic sense.  Similarly, the outcome cannot be traced to a specific cause, so it is not causal.

Comment: The outcome of a QM experiment is causal only to the extent that the outcome of a throw of random dice is causal.  It can be said that the outcome was in some sense caused by the dice throw (since it wouldn't have happened at all if the dice hadn't been thrown), but it cannot be said that the specific outcome was *determined* by the dice throw, because identical throws can produce completely different outcomes.

Comment: Yes, I am using "causal" in the common sense of special relativity, because that's the actual law which constrains how objects behave. I am not talking about determinism.

Comment: In Special Relativity, "causality" relates more to *order of occurrence* than to "causes" *per se*.  To paraphrase Wikipedia (Causality (physics),  *In special relativity, causality means that an effect can not occur from a cause that is not in the back (past) light cone of that event.*  The word "causality" in the ordinary context means that all effects must have specific causes.*  The OP built his/her question from: "This *lack of cause* is ...", so the OP is asking about causes, not ordering of events.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are getting at, but there are a few misunderstandings in your post.

For example, "...so electron decides where to go for itself" is not how electrons work. Electrons are governed by physical laws, which provide a set of states that the electron can exist in. We may not know which state the electron is in before measuring, but neither does the electron. Once any measurement is made (including the electron measuring where they are), the answer is known.

More generally, measurement results are "random", but each possible result must obey the laws of physics - and one of those laws is causality. So every possible state that a particular system can be in *does* obey causality, even if we don't know which state is it before measuring.

In principle, theories of quantum gravity might have causality-violating states, in the same way quantum mechanics has states which violate classical mechanics. People are working on that:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.10066

Comment: "each possible result must obey the laws of physics" means that those stochastic outcomes are caused by some non-stochastic, determined laws, but this "are caused" means that we can potentially (if we knew everything) determine the outcome and so it wouldn't be stochastic anymore. But we know that those phenomena are indeed stochastic and there is no way to predict them. If there is no way to predict them, so how can they be causal?If I have two similar measurements, I can get two different outcomes. If nothing (and so no cause) differs, so how can I have varying results?

Comment: When I use "causal" I mean it in the sense of Special Relativity. For example, I leave my house at 9 am. There are a collection of places I can be at 10 am, but not on that list is the other side of the Solar System, because that would violate causality. Similarly with an electron in an atom - we use the laws of physics to determine the possible states, all of which obey causality and relevant dynamical laws (Schrodinger, in this case), and each state has an assigned probability.

Comment: Once you have set up all the possible states, you make a measurement to determine what state the system is actually in. Notice that I have not made reference to an "initial state", because that's an actual measurement, collapsing the wavefunction. Which isn't to say QM isn't dynamical; the evolution of the quantum system is also a dynamical process, until measurements are made.

Comment: Thanks, I have understood from another question that quantum systems are causal. Thanks for your help.